# Take two different values from a single SQL query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is there a way to simplify/optimise this mysql/mariadb query?
Ultimately I need two individual pieces of data from a single query: the latest transaction name and sum of all transaction payment amounts.

This works but is ugly because it repeats the JOINS and WHERE clauses:

```
    SELECT
        SUM(btp.allocated_amount),
        (
        SELECT
            bt.name
        FROM
            `tabBank Transaction Payments` as btp
        LEFT JOIN
            `tabBank Transaction` bt ON bt.name=btp.parent
        WHERE
            btp.payment_document = 'Journal Entry'
        AND
            bt.docstatus = 1
        ORDER BY
            bt.date desc
        LIMIT 1
        ) AS name
        FROM
            `tabBank Transaction Payments` as btp
        LEFT JOIN
            `tabBank Transaction` bt ON bt.name=btp.parent
        WHERE
            btp.payment_document = 'Journal Entry'
        AND
            bt.docstatus = 1;
```

I thought something like this would work but it doesn't. The name given is arbitrary and not the first according to the ORDER BY:

```
        SELECT
        (SELECT SUM(allocated_amount)),
        (SELECT name LIMIT 1)
        FROM
        (
        SELECT
            btp.allocated_amount,
            bt.name
        FROM
            `tabBank Transaction Payments` as btp
        LEFT JOIN
            `tabBank Transaction` bt ON bt.name=btp.parent
        WHERE
            btp.payment_document = 'Journal Entry'
        AND
            bt.docstatus = 1
        ORDER BY
            bt.date desc
        ) AS temp;
```

Edit:

Example data (NOTE: example has been simplified):

tabBank Transaction Payments

```
| parent | payment_document | allocated_amount |
------------------------------------------------
| doc1   | Journal Entry    | 10.00            |
| doc1   | Journal Entry20  | 4000.00          |
| doc2   | Journal Entry    | 20.00            |
| doc2   | Journal Entry20  | 5000.00          |
| doc3   | Journal Entry    | 30.00            |
| doc3   | Journal Entry20  | 6000.00          |
```

tabBank Transaction

```
| name | date       | docstatus |
---------------------------------
| doc1 | 2022-01-01 | 1         |
| doc2 | 2022-02-01 | 1         |
| doc3 | 2022-03-01 | 1         |
```

Required result:
(60.00, doc3)

mariadb version: 10.2.27

Comment: What's your mysql version

Comment: @D-Shih version added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to D-Shih for the suggestion and intro to window functions which I didn't know existed. I simplified and ended up with this.

For other scenarios where you need more than one result row due to partitioning, the `ROW_NUMBER()` will be required.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        SUM(btp.allocated_amount) OVER() total_allocated_amount,
        FIRST_VALUE(bt.name) OVER(ORDER BY bt.date desc) latest_name
    FROM
        `tabBank Transaction Payments` as btp
    LEFT JOIN
        `tabBank Transaction` bt ON bt.name=btp.parent
    WHERE
        btp.payment_document = 'Journal Entry'
    AND
        bt.docstatus = 1
) t1
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` & `SUM` window functions to make it.

`ROW_NUMBER` get the lastest row of name by `bt.date desc`

`OVER` clause is essential to window functions, that perform calculations based on a set of records and `PARTITION BY` defines the groups into which the rows are divided.

More detail we can see [Window Function Concepts and Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html)

```
SELECT total_allocated_amount,name
FROM (
    SELECT
        SUM(btp.allocated_amount) OVER() total_allocated_amount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY bt.date desc) rn,
        bt.name
    FROM
        `tabBank Transaction Payments` as btp
    LEFT JOIN
        `tabBank Transaction` bt ON bt.name=btp.parent
    WHERE
        btp.payment_document = 'Journal Entry'
    AND
        bt.docstatus = 1
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=ef2ef0c35b736c6c5cf11e4521da8afb)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems this can be simplified. The ROW_NUMBER is unnecessary because the name is already unique, and we can just use LIMIT 1 to get the first entry. It seems the main thing that makes it work is OVER() after the SUM which gives the same sum for each row of the subquery. Could you simplify and explain what OVER does please?

Comment: @racitup I had added more explain about window function

Comment: your link is broken but thanks